# TSQL conditional join for values in second table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to do conditional join on two tables and wanted to join with highest status in the second table. The status values are Assigned, Booked, Delivery and Closed.

```
SELECT 
    CPC.CpcID, StatusFlow = CPC.Status, Orders.CarModel, EnquiryLog.EnquiryStatus
FROM 
    CPC
INNER JOIN 
    Orders ON CPC.CpcID = Orders.CpcID    
INNER JOIN 
    EnquiryLog ON CPC.CpcID = EnquiryLog.CpcID
WHERE 
    CPC.CpcID = '24092015/12'
```

So in this case it should show only one row with EnquiryStatus 'Delivery' but based on my query the result is:

SQL query output:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you filter for that status?

Comment: When there are multiple CpcID then filter will always do not work.

Comment: Provide some data we can work with. And the desired output for that data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it the right way:

```
SELECT CPC.CpcID, StatusFlow = CPC.Status, Orders.CarModel, ca.EnquiryStatus
FROM CPC
INNER JOIN Orders ON CPC.CpcID = Orders.CpcID    
CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM EnquiryLog WHERE CPC.CpcID = EnquiryLog.CpcID
            ORDER BY CASE EnquiryStatus
                          WHEN 'CLOSED' THEN 1
                          WHEN 'DELIVERY' THEN 2
                          WHEN 'BOOKED' THEN 3
                          WHEN 'ASSIGNED' THEN 4 END) ca
WHERE CPC.CpcID='24092015/12'
```

Comment: Hello Giorgi, there is some problem with this query .. Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.